# How do I understand the calculation of degrees of freedom in the context of a 2 x 3 contingency table?

Tags: chi-squared-test, degrees-of-freedom

I am currently reading an article, [Analysis of sensory ratings data with cumulative link models](https://backend.orbit.dtu.dk/ws/portalfiles/portal/79012845/Christensen+and+Brockhoff+2013.pdf). In section 2.4 - example 1, the authors describe an experiment from Bi, 2002*:

> ... 25 subjects each assess four concordant and four discordant product pairs. The subjects were asked to rate the degree of difference between the sample product pairs on a three point rating scale, where 1 means identical and 3 means different.

The experiment resulted in a 2 x 3 contingency table (please see Table 1 in the paper), and later, to show the application of Pearson $\chi^2$-test statistic, the authors motivated an assumption of non-repeated measures (across six cells of the table). Once the test statistic was calculated (X$^2$ = 6.49), it was assumed to follow a $\chi^2$ distribution with two degrees of freedom. However, I am not sure why the sampling distribution of $X^2$ is assumed to follow $\chi^2_2$ i.e., why are the degrees of freedom two? Could it be possible that the degrees of freedom (DoF) are non-integral in this case?

I have read the related post, ['How to understand degrees of freedom'](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/how-to-understand-degrees-of-freedom), but was wondering if I could calculate the DoF without relying on any heuristic - I am not even sure what kind of heuristic would be the most accurate in this case.

---

*Bi, J. (2002). Statistical models for the degree of difference test. Food Quality and Preference, 13:13–37.)

Comment: Assuming you're familiar with the explanations in the large literature and CV threads you're linked to, I'm puzzled why you still have a question. So, what do you mean by not *relying on any heuristic?* Add Bishop's classic *Multidimensional Contingency Tables* Moreover, as good as the work in the links is (e.g., Christiansen's biblio is awesome), they are dated. More recent work is available. Search Google Books for Howard Moskowitz on sensory economics and perception. Wickens' 2014 book *Multiway Contingency Tables Analysis for the Social Sciences* for applied depth wrt explaining DoFs